# How to search for item using .NET Core Graph API SDK?

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

How do I do a rough search for a DriveItem in the Graph API using the .NET Graph SDK?

Note: This is querying a SharePoint drive.

Attempted:

```
var driveItemCollectionPage = await _graphApiClient.Sites[SiteId].Drives[DriveId].Root
    .Children.Request().Filter($"name eq '{searchTerm}'").GetAsync();
```

This is using strict equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Search:

Example:

```
var driveItemCollectionPage = await _graphApiClient.Sites[SiteId].Drives[DriveId].Root
    .ItemWithPath(folderPath).Search(searchTerm).Request().GetAsync();
```

Returns an array of DriveItem that match the given search term.

[Microsoft Graph API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)